# how to layoutInDisplayCutoutMode Never on android api 27?

Tags: android, display-cutouts

this code perfect working for api level 28. How to do this on android api 27?

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {   
      window.attributes.layoutInDisplayCutoutMode = LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_NEVER       
}
```

I tried this but it's not working

```
<style name="PlayerTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">#000000</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode" tools:targetApi="27">
            never
        </item>
    </style>
```